# Adding Animation to SCNNode while dropping in Scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I can place/rotate/move `SCNNode` or 3D model in SceneKit but currently it is not a good user experience.

How can I place a model in SceneKit like in the Ikea Place app with `SCNAction`?

for the reference my desired output is like this video, demonstrating the Ikea Place app:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OS_kScr0XkQ

Answer (score 0):

You can chain Scenekit animations together and run them in a sequence to produce the desired effect.  This post: 58001288 (answer predefined sequences) describes ways to do that.  You can fade in, bounce, add extra effect objects and remove them when placing. What you need is there, you just have to get a little creative.

Comment: can you please help me out with some sample code or git.

Comment: I see the chair moving up and down in the video - so you just keep repeating a sequence of moves up and down (y-N, y+N) until they drop the object - at the point, you should have a destination point - then it's just move from wherever you are to that point with a small duration.  There is an example of a heartbeat type sequence in the link I sent.